# Can´t add product to cart, litespeed and sm-maxshop theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, litespeed

Im trying to get litespeed cache to work with my magento installation.
Litespeed is working and load speed is faster. The problem is when a user tries to add a product to the cart in product page, it doesn't add the product.

Add-button is working fine when litespeed is disabled.
Is there a way to exclude the addbutton from caching.

Magento 1.9.2.3
Lightspeed Cache from litespeedtech 1.3.6
SM-Maxshop theme 1.1.0

Comment: Are you getting error when trying to add to cart? It could be that form key is cached, so CSRF check is failing.

Comment: No errors. Button just has no function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Usually there are some coding to fix issues like this so I thougt this was the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe some javascript breaking if that button does not work. Does your footer show up properly? There's one [known issue](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:litemage:troubleshooting:uninitialized-php-vars-injected-block) for sm theme. If this is not your case, you can create a ticket with LiteSpeed support, they can help you there. 
LiteMage is very flexible and can be configured to fit most cases for Magento 1.9. FormKey is handled as a private ESI block and should not break CSRF check.

Comment: Footer seems to be ok. I tried the known issue for sm-theme but still the same.